# Angular 2 error directives

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I could use some help over this, I'm learning about ANGULAR 2 routing, I'm getting this error:

> app/app.component.ts(7,12): error TS2345: Argument of type '{
>   selector: string; templateUrl: string; directives: (typeof
>   PeliculasListComponent | typeof Peli...' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '{ selector?: string; inputs?: string[]; outputs?:
>   string[]; properties?: string[]; events?: strin...'.   Types of
>   property 'directives' are incompatible.
>       Type '(typeof PeliculasListComponent | typeof PeliculasFooterComponent | typeof "C:/UwAmp/www/curso-ang...' is not
>   assignable to type '(Type | any[])[]'.
>         Type 'typeof PeliculasListComponent | typeof PeliculasFooterComponent | typeof "C:/UwAmp/www/curso-angu...' is not
>   assignable to type 'Type | any[]'.
>           Type 'typeof "C:/UwAmp/www/curso-angular/app/components/contacto.component"' is not
>   assignable to type 'Type | any[]'.
>             Type 'typeof "C:/UwAmp/www/curso-angular/app/components/contacto.component"' is not
>   assignable to type 'any[]'.
>               Property 'length' is missing in type 'typeof "C:/UwAmp/www/curso-angular/app/components/contacto.component"'.
>   app/app.component.ts(16,14): error TS2345: Argument of type '({ path:
>   string; name: string; component: typeof PeliculasListComponent;
>   useAsDefault: boolean; }...' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'RouteDefinition[]'.   Type '{ path: string; name: string; component:
>   typeof PeliculasListComponent; useAsDefault: boolean; } ...' is not
>   assignable to type 'RouteDefinition'.
>       Type '{ path: string; name: string; component: typeof "C:/UwAmp/www/curso-angular/app/components/contac...' is not
>   assignable to type 'RouteDefinition'.
>         Types of property 'component' are incompatible.
>           Type 'typeof "C:/UwAmp/www/curso-angular/app/components/contacto.component"' is not
>   assignable to type 'Type | ComponentDefinition'.
>             Type 'typeof "C:/UwAmp/www/curso-angular/app/components/contacto.component"' is not
>   assignable to type 'ComponentDefinition'.
>               Property 'type' is missing in type 'typeof "C:/UwAmp/www/curso-angular/app/components/contacto.component"'.

This is my code:

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {PeliculasListComponent} from "./components/peliculas-list.component";
import {PeliculasFooterComponent} from "./components/peliculas-footer.component";
import ContactoComponent from "./components/contacto.component";

import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig, Router} from "angular2/router";
@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app/views/peliculas.html",
    directives: [PeliculasListComponent,
                 PeliculasFooterComponent,
                 ContactoComponent, 
                 ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: "/peliculas", name:"Peliculas", component: PeliculasListComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: "/contacto", name:"Contacto", component: ContactoComponent}*/
])

export class AppComponent{
    public titulo:string = "Peliculas con angular" ;

}
```

Do yoy have any ideas how to solve it? THANKS!!

Comment: It looks like you might have upgraded your version of angular 2 and are working on a project written with a beta version.  Routing and directives (imports) now belong in the NgModule

Comment: @JasonGoemaat just to expand on your point little bit, this app is written in a legacy version that will be very hard to find documentation on and has a likely unknown set of bugs and issues. If you are just starting out please upgrade to the latest as things have changed. If you're maintaining an existing application then gods help you.

Comment: I didn't think the process was all that difficult, it may be more difficult if you are just starting with the project and not familiar with how things were done in the beta in the first place.  You can look at [the NgModule docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) and [this guide](https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/08/13/updating-your-angular-2-app-from-rc4-to-rc5-a-practical-guide/) on updating from RC4 to RC5 when they introduced NgModule.  Basically create new NgModule and move declarations from components to it and change bootstrapping.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using an outdated version of a release candidate from angular, like mentioned in the comments.
Because there is **no directives** attribute according to the latest documentation **in the component decorator**:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html

---

Start with the guides from [angular.io](http://angular.io), there are many examples.

Otherwise start with the angular seed project, where everything is configured:

https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Try this guide from angular directly, it covers pretty much everything you need for the start:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html